# I can't verify that the environment variable "SECRET_KEY_BASE" is properly set in Linux with this command: $ printenv | grep SECRET_KEY_BASE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, heroku, vim

My ruby ​​version is 2.6.6, my mysql version is 8.0.23, my mysql2 version is 0.5.3, my bundler version is 2.2.21, my rails version is 5.0.7.2, and my Xcode version is 12.5.

I use macOS Big Sur(version 11.4) and the text editor "Atom".

I'm planning to release my Rails application with the URL of HEROKU(example. https://[My APP Name].herokuapp.com).

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku open
```

The following error occured.

```
An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.
```

I set two environment variables as below with this command: `$ heroku config:set [ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE NAME]`.

```
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_USERNAME=****
```

```
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_PASSWORD=****
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku config

DATABASE_PASSWORD: ****
DATABASE_URL: postgres://****
DATABASE_USERNAME: ****
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA_URL: postgres://****
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL: postgres://****
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV: production
RAILS_ENV: production
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: enabled
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: enabled
```

I ran the following command to get `GENERATED_CODE`.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake secret

GENERATED_CODE
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ vi /etc/profile
```

I set the environment variable "SECRET_KEY_BASE" as below in Vim editor.

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi

$ export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
```

I saved the above `SECRET_KEY_BASE` and ended Vim editor with the two below commands.

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

```
:q!
```

I opened the vim editor again as below with this command:`$ vi /etc/profile`.

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi

$ export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE

"/etc/profile" [readonly] 13L, 346B
```

I ran the two following command for verifying that the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` is properly set in Linux.

```
$ printenv | grep SECRET_KEY_BASE
```

```
$ echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE
```

But I can't verify that the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` is properly set in Linux with this command:

```
$ printenv | grep SECRET_KEY_BASE
```

or with:

```
$ echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE
```

Would you like to tell me the reason why I can't verify that the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` is properly set in Linux with the two following command?

```
$ printenv | grep SECRET_KEY_BASE`
```

```
$ echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE
```

Comment: Did you source that file or start a new session before testing if the environment variable was set?

Comment: I don't get the file '$ vi /etc/profile' and don't start a new session before testing if the environment variable "SECRET_KEY_BASE" was set. So would you like to tell me the way to get the file '$ vi /etc/profile' and to start a new session?

Comment: I don't know what "get" means in your comment. You *source* a script in your shell by doing `$ source /path/to/file`. As for starting a new session, quit the current session and start a new one. If you don't know how to do that there are hundreds (thousands?) of "unix shell" tutorials on the web. There is no point whatsoever playing with Heroku if you don't know how to use a shell.

Comment: do you really have this line in `/etc/profile` that starts with a literal `$`: `$ export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE`? if so, remove the `$` (you don't include your command prompt in the file); the command `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE` says to assign the literal string `"GENERATED_CODE"` to the variable `SECRET_KEYBASE` ... is this what you want or is `GENERATED_CODE` also a variable? if `GENERATED_CODE` is a variable then you need to preface the variable name with a `$` => `export SECRET_KEY_BASE="${GENERATED_CODE}"`

Comment: what is this supposed to do: `RAILS_ENV=production rake secret`? is `production` a command with 2 arguments: `rake` and `secret`? or are you trying to assign the literal string '"production rake secret"` to the `RAILS_ENV` variable?